# Print out images from custom field wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field called images, I am attempting to loop through my custom post and for each post print out 3 images. I've started them in an array but whenever I try to print the contents of the area I get weird output, like the images duplicating. I've attempted a simple while loop but instead of limiting it to 3 it prints out every image attached.

```
<?php $i=0; while ($page_query->have_posts()): $page_query->the_post(); ?> 
        <section class="featured-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="title-button center-block"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of col md 12 -->
                </div>
                <div class="row home-img-row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 <?php print the_ID(); ?>">
                    <?php $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images');
                    $i = 0; ?>
                    <? while ($i < 3) {
                        print($meta_values[$i]);
                        $i++;
                    }?>
```

Comment: Is there a endwhile missing in the first while loop?

Comment: I didn't print the rest of the code as its just the closing tags and the end of the first while loop

Comment: Is this resolved for you? If not, let us know so we can help more. Otherwise, would you mind marking the most helpful answer as "accepted"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might help to debug your `$meta_values` variable. Also, keep your PHP open tags consistent (`<?php` is highly preferable). You would also probably want to do a `foreach` loop on an array, vs a while loop.

```
<?php
$meta_values = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images');
var_dump($meta_values); // Debug
foreach ($meta_values as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: Declare $meta_values as a array
$meta_values[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images');

Comment: @Reshil That is incorrect. You're now adding the array of the function return into a single arbitrary array key...

Comment: I attempted this but it still prints out every item.

              <?php $meta_values = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'images',false);
                    ?>
                    <?php foreach(array_slice($meta_values,0,3) as $value) {
      echo $value;
     } ?>

Comment: You used my example code above, and saw the var_dump output? Did that help you? If you're still stuck, run my example code again, and update your post with the var_dump output of $meta_values.

Comment: @BitwiseCreative Yes u r right..
NicolasPocock You have to put a break,inside foreach to terminate after iterating 3 times
eg
$i=0;
foreach ($meta_values as $value) {
    echo $value;
    if($i==2) break;
    $i++;
}

Comment: @Reshil We can't be certain of that solution unless we see the var_dump output. It could be that they are in an order that would require more work than simply breaking after the first three iterations.